# How to add a non-modular Maven dependency to the module path as an automatic module?

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system, org.json

Lets say we would like to build a simple Java 11 modular Maven project with a single non-modular dependency `org.json:json` (picked at random for the sake of a practical example).

Project structure:

```
project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- java
            |-- foo.bar.project
            |   `-- foo
            |       `-- bar
            |           `-- project
            |               `-- Foo.java
            `-- module-info.java
```

**`Foo.java`**:

```
package foo.bar.project;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Foo {
    static JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
}
```

**`module-info.java`**:

```
module foo.bar.project {
}
```

**`pom.xml`**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20200518</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <id>compile</id>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

My question is how to tell Maven to put `org.json` on the module path as an *automatic module*. By default, Maven places non-modular jars on the `classpath` as *unnamed modules*.

As it stands, running `mvn clean compile` fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project project: Compilation failure
[ERROR] <PathToProject>/src/main/java/foo.bar.project/foo/bar/project/Foo.java:[3,11] package org.json is not visible
[ERROR]   (package org.json is declared in the unnamed module, but module org.json does not read it)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

---

System info:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.6.0
Java version: 11.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1
Default locale: sl_SI, platform encoding: UTF8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ii find the message

> [ERROR]   (package org.json is declared in the unnamed module, but
> module org.json does not read it)

strange, it should have read *"..but module `foo.bar.project` does not read it"*.

Then you would have found that you need to place a directive in `module-info.java` such as:

```
requires org.json;
```

Comment: Though I was using `apache-maven-3.6.3` and `JDK 14-ea` to reproduce the issue you have shared.

Comment: I have double-checked my error message and I am positive there was no typo. Still, your solution works, thank you!